# Python: Need help comparing two lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, search, compare

I recently discovered a huge bug in my script and I need some help figuring it out.

This script searches through multiple sub-directories in our codebase and finds all source files that fall into a certain criteria and makes a list of the names. I call this list: `all_files`

It then runs another program, and this program makes new source files (close to the same names) that get placed in another directory. I go into that directory and make a list of the file names in there. I call this list: `covered_files`

Now here's the problem, the new source file names differ in that they have leading words. For example:

--> file name in `all_files`: fileName.cpp

--> file name in `covered_files`: prefix_fileName.cpp

These two files correspond to each other, and the job of this script is to return a list of names from `all_files` that show up in `covered_files`... That is, in the above example the name "fileName.cpp" would be added to the list because it is in both.

One main issue is that there are names that would correspond to "fileName1.cpp", fileName2.cpp", and so on. And as you'll see in my code below, it only accounts for one of these files being covered when they both need to be.

What I currently have:

```
def find_covered_files(all_files):

    covered_path = <path to the newly generated files>

    # Make a list of every file in the covered folder
    covered_files = [f for f in listdir(covered_path) if isfile(join(covered_path, f))]
   
    file_match_list = []

    # Seach through the covered files for matches
    for cov_file in covered_files:
        # Find the file matches
        for files in all_files:
            if files in cov_file:
                file_match_list.append(files)

    return file_match_list
```

So overall my question is: Is there a way to search through the two lists, where one of the entries is a substring of the other, that will give me each file name that is covered regardless if that substring appears more than once? Thank you in advance for any help!

Edit: Another example using some actual file names:

There are files `Segment.cpp`, `SegmentAllocation.cpp`, and `SegmentImpl.cpp` These would be in the `all_files` list with the matching prefixed names in the `covered_files` list.

After the code is ran, I would expect all three of them to be in the `file_match_list`. However, only the first file name is in there repeated 3 times.

So instead of: (desired)

```
['Segment.cpp', 'SegmentAllocation.cpp', 'SegmentImpl.cpp']
```

I get:

```
['Segment.cpp', 'Segment.cpp', 'Segment.cpp']
```

Comment: Can you clarify "it only accounts for one of these files being covered when they both need to be"? Would `fileName.cpp` not be added twice since it appears in two `cov_file`s?

Comment: @MarioIshac Yes I'll use an example from the actual codebase.

Comment: Is the matching prefixed name for `SegmentImpl.cpp` `prefix_SegmentImpl.cpp` or `prefix_Segment.cpp`?

Comment: Did you try to do some debugging? Are the values of `cov_file` and `files` inside the loop what you expect them to be?

Comment: @MarioIshac for SegmentImpl.cpp, the corresponding file is prefix_SegmentImpl.cpp

Comment: @mkrieger1 I apologize, I copy and pasted it without being careful with indents. Should be fixed now

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes I'm currently going through the debugging right now, the problem is there are 9,000 source files in the code base so its going to take me a minute to find the errors....

Answer (score 0):

I answered the question after debugging, I needed a break statement in the for loop:

def find_covered_files(all_files):

```
covered_path = <path to the newly generated files>

# Make a list of every file in the covered folder
covered_files = [f for f in listdir(covered_path) if isfile(join(covered_path, f))]

file_match_list = []

# Seach through the covered files for matches
for cov_file in covered_files:
    # Find the file matches
    for files in all_files:
        if files in cov_file:
            file_match_list.append(files)
            break


return file_match_list
```